# taro build show mini-css-extract-plugin warning: Conflicting order. how to solve it?

Tags: mini-css-extract-plugin

I start a taro + react project, build show mini-css-extract-plugin warning:

> Error: chunk common [mini-css-extract-plugin]
> Conflicting order. Following module has been added: ***

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

in `config/index.js` file add follow setting in mini config:

```js
mini: {
    enableExtract:true,
    miniCssExtractPluginOption: {
        ignoreOrder: true
    },
}
```

link for origin answer: https://juejin.cn/post/7036177994301308936